# Running a js code on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a third-party javascript code which communicates with their web server and which I want to run **periodically** **on the server**. I'm not that familiar with NodeJS so that's why I don't know exactly wether it'll help me or not, although I've read some articles about that topic. The task is run that script on the server exactly as it were in a browser on the client. Is it possible to do with NodeJS?

Answer (score 2):

> The task is run that script on the server exactly as it were in a browser on the client. Is it possible to do with NodeJS?

Very nearly, yes. What you're looking for is a "headless browser" with a JavaScript API and/or NodeJS module. Specific recommendations are not what SO is for, but that's the term to search for, and I'll note that both jQuery and Sizzle projects (closely related) use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). (I haven't used it directly, just as a byproduct of contributing to projects that do.) It's not a NodeJS module (it has to run in its own process), but you can launch it from Node as a project and then interact with it.

Then you load whatever assets you need into the headless browser, including the JavaScript you need to run.

Needless to say, you need to ***really*** trust the source of any code you receive and run on your server. :-)